# Предлоги и падежи в дискуссии о Марианской впадине

Tags: предлоги, падежи

Самое глубокое место – Марианская впадина

...Первыми людьми, которые лично **погружались** **к дну** Марианской впадины, стали швейцарский океанолог Жак Пикар и военнослужащий США Дон Уолш. Это произошло в январе 1960 года на специальном круглом батискафе под названием Триест. Велико было удивление ученых, когда на такой огромной глубине они **встретили плоских рыб и других живых организмов**. Позже в 1995 году японский...

© Inga Korneshova. Статья написана специально для 100facts.ru
 Копирование без указания источника запрещено!
Автор публикации: Inga Korneshova
Копирование текстов с сайта разрешается только при указании источника!

Смотрели  REN TV. Заспорили о Марианской впадине. Статья в Интернете удовлетворила интерес к глубине, но разогрела другой.

Я считаю, что:
погружались - куда? к чему? - КО ДНУ
встретили - что? - И ДРУГИЕ ЖИВЫЕ ОРГАНИЗМЫ.

Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Погружались ко дну**

Выбор предлога К/КО  зависит от различных факторов (удобство произношения, традиции и т.д.):

- [к — ко | academic.ru](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/689/%D0%BA_%E2%80%94_%D0%BA%D0%BE)
- [К Дню знаний или ко Дню знаний? | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=69)

**2) Они встретили плоских рыб и другие живые организмы**

Сравнить: вирус поражает живые организмы

Существительное "организм" **является неодушевленным с точки зрения грамматики**, поэтому винительный падеж совпадает с именительным

Comment: Довольна, что интуитивно оказалась права.  Вам, Сибилла, поклон за вселенские знания.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы задаете интересные  вопросы.

Comment: Погружаться  - опускаться во что-либо. Разве можно сказать  "погружаться к чему-то"? Если я не прав, помогите понять.

Comment: "погружаться"  =  опускаться во что-либо (жидкость, снег, песок и т. п.), совершенно верно.  Тогда фраза будет звучать так: ...они опускались в воде ко дну...

Comment: Можно еще пример:  ...iPhone 5s в алюминиевом боксе выдерживает погружение до 100 м,  т.е.  ...выдерживает опускание в воде до 100 м.